# ( Flutter Bloc ) doesn't conform to the bound 'StateStreamable<state>' of the type parameter 'B'

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

why am i getting the error? I couldn't find the reason. I'll be happy if you can help me.

[error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b58al.png)

[You can check my issue on github](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/3322)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 9):

hello i solved the problem. The problem was giving an error because there were 2 classes with the same name, so my StatefulWidget class name was the same as my block state class name :) It was fixed when I changed the name of my block state class.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use same name for StatefulWidget state and use again that name in block or state please dont repeat same name that's wht that errors come

Answer (score 0):

this happens when

1. You have two classes with the same name
2. You add the bloc instead of the event

ex:

```dart
class CounterBloc extends Bloc<CounterBloc, CounterState> {
  CounterBloc() : super(const InitialState()) {
    on<IncrementEvent>((event, emit) {
      emit(IncrementedCounterState());
    });
    on<IncrementEvent>((event, emit) {
      emit(DecrementedCounterState());
    });
  }
}
```

I should pass the Event not the bloc in the `Bloc<CounterBloc,CounterState>` and it should be `Bloc<CounterEvent,CounterState>`

3. I will update it with more.

Answer (score 0):

If the following primary cause for this issue :

```
there were 2 classes with the same name
```

is not the solution , or you have already fixed it and still having the problem,

Simply run the `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` command to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

Apart from other solutions also check if you have given type of bloc

> class NewsBloc extends Bloc<NewsEvent, NewsState>

if you haven't given <NewsEvent, NewsState> it will give same error.